# Getting PHP error after enabling Braintree card payment method in Magento 2.4.5 Fresh Installation Setup

Tags: magento2, braintree, reorder

Getting an error when enabling the Braintree payment method when clicking on reorder from the order view page on the admin side, can you please help me resolve this issue?

Error is = Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in /var/www/html/local.magento245-sample-data.com/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Block/Form.php:174

Steps to reproduce this issue:

1. Enable the Stores->Configuration->Sales->Payment Methods->Braintree (click on
   configure)-> Enable Card payments (Set to Yes)
2. Go to an order view page , and click on reorder and also try canceling that order and again click on reorder , you will get this error screenshot attached

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the official patch like provided in this official support article:
https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/8322266352525-Admin-can-t-create-order-reorder-when-Braintree-payment-enabled

You can choose this method to apply via composer:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/apply.html

Finally at this link you can see all available patches by release or other parameters:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/tools/commerce-quality-patches/index.html